# Laravel Mix: custom node_modules path

Tags: webpack, laravel-mix

When running `npx mix`, I get the error:

```
ERROR in ../src/js/components/TestComponent.vue?vue&type=template&id=0ac5fdef (./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js??clonedRuleSet-5.use[0]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/templateLoader.js??ruleSet[1].rules[2]!./node_modules/vue-loader/dist/index.js??ruleSet[0].use[0]!../src/js/components/TestComponent.vue?vue&type=template&id=0ac5fdef) 1:0-126
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/var/www/project/src/js/components'

ERROR in ../src/js/app.js 1:0-32
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'vue' in '/var/www/project/src/js'

webpack compiled with 2 errors
```

My folder structure looks like:

```
buildchain
 - node_modules
 - package.json
 - tailwind.config.js
 - webpack.mix.js

cms
docker-config
src
  - js
    - app.js
```

app.js

```
import { createApp } from "vue";

import TestComponent from "./components/TestComponent.vue";

const app = createApp({
    components: {
      TestComponent
    }
  });
  
  app.mount("#app");
```

webpack.mix.js

```
// webpack.mix.js

let mix = require('laravel-mix');

let path = require('path');




mix.js("../src/js/app.js", "js")
    .vue()
    .postCss('../src/css/app.css', 'css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .setPublicPath('../cms/web/assets')
```

If I change my vue import to `import { createApp } from "../../buildchain/node_modules/vue";`, the error goes away, but still remains in `TestComponent.vue`.

How can I have it so my files can automatically find `node_modules` and import correctly?

Edit:

Tried:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    }
});
```

But I still get the error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up fixing this by using the Path library:

Install path with npm, then include it in the webpack.mix.js file:

`let path = require('path');`

change:

```
mix.webpackConfig({
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    }
});
```

to:

```
.webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
            ]
        }
    })
```

webpack.mix.js:

```
mix.js("../src/js/app.js", "js")
    .vue()
    .postCss('../src/css/app.css', 'css', [
        require("tailwindcss"),
    ])
    .webpackConfig({
        resolve: {
            modules: [
                path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
            ]
        }
    })
    .setPublicPath('../cms/web/assets')
```